# TensorFlow crashes when fitting TensorForestEstimator

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to fit at `TensorForestEstimator` model with numerical floating-point data representing 7 features and 7 labels. That is, the shape of both `features` and `labels` is `(484876, 7)`. I set `num_classes=7` and `num_features=7` in `ForestHParams`appropriately. The format of the data is as follows:

```
f1       f2     f3    f4      f5    f6    f7   l1       l2       l3       l4       l5       l6       l7
39000.0  120.0  65.0  1000.0  25.0  0.69  3.94 39000.0  39959.0  42099.0  46153.0  49969.0  54127.0  55911.0
32000.0  185.0  65.0  1000.0  75.0  0.46  2.19 32000.0  37813.0  43074.0  48528.0  54273.0  60885.0  63810.0 
30000.0  185.0  65.0  1000.0  25.0  0.41  1.80 30000.0  32481.0  35409.0  39145.0  42750.0  46678.0  48595.0
```

When calling `fit()` Python crashes with the following message:

> Python quit unexpectedly while using the _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so plug-in.

Here is the output when enabling `tf.logging.set_verbosity('INFO')`:

```
INFO:tensorflow:training graph for tree: 0
INFO:tensorflow:training graph for tree: 1
... 
INFO:tensorflow:training graph for tree: 9998
INFO:tensorflow:training graph for tree: 9999
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
2017-07-26 10:25:30.908894: F tensorflow/contrib/tensor_forest/kernels/count_extremely_random_stats_op.cc:404] 
Check failed: column < num_classes_ (39001 vs. 8)

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

I'm not sure what this error means, it doesn't really make sense since `num_classes=7`, not 8 and as the shape of features and labels is `(484876, 7)`, I don't know where the 39001 is coming from.

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

def get_training_data():
    training_file = "data.txt"
    data = pd.read_csv(training_file, sep='\t')

    X = np.array(data.drop('Result', axis=1), dtype=np.float32)

    y = []
    for e in data.ResultStr:
        y.append(list(np.array(str(e).replace('[', '').replace(']', '').split(','))))

    y = np.array(y, dtype=np.float32)

    features = tf.constant(X)
    labels = tf.constant(y)

    return features, labels

hyperparameters = ForestHParams(
    num_trees=100,
    max_nodes=10000,
    bagging_fraction=1.0,
    num_splits_to_consider=0,
    feature_bagging_fraction=1.0,
    max_fertile_nodes=0,
    split_after_samples=250,
    min_split_samples=5,
    valid_leaf_threshold=1,
    dominate_method='bootstrap',
    dominate_fraction=0.99,
    # All parameters above are default
    num_classes=7,
    num_features=7
)

estimator = TensorForestEstimator(
    params=hyperparameters,
    # All parameters below are default
    device_assigner=None,
    model_dir=None,
    graph_builder_class=RandomForestGraphs,
    config=None,
    weights_name=None,
    keys_name=None,
    feature_engineering_fn=None,
    early_stopping_rounds=100,
    num_trainers=1,
    trainer_id=0,
    report_feature_importances=False,
    local_eval=False
)

estimator.fit(
    input_fn=lambda: get_training_data(),
    max_steps=100,
    monitors=[
        TensorForestLossHook(
            early_stopping_rounds=30
        )
    ]
)
```

It also doesn't work if I wrap it with `SKCompat`, the same error occur. What is the cause of this crash?

Comment: Can you provide sample input data?

Comment: I edited the question to provide input data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`regression=True` needs to be specified in the `ForestHParams` because `TensorForestEstimator` by default assumes that it is being used to solve a  classification problem, which can only output one value.

There is an implicit `num_outputs` variable created upon initialization of the estimator and it is set to `1` if `regression` was not specified. If `regression` is specified, then `num_outputs = num_classes` and checkpoints are saved normally.